# MDI Child Window Size

Tags: c++, winapi, mdi, mdichild

I am trying to create a child window within an MDI MainWindow...The main window is 1024 x 768 in size...when I try to use CreateWindowEx() to create a child window the size seems to be offset somehow...in other words a 1024 x 768 child window is smaller than its parent...how can I account for this difference? When I use GetCLientRect() with the main window's handle...the size is still smaller...I don't care to make the child window the same size. I want the child window to encompass the exact size of an image that is 750x563. When I set that size within the parameters of CreateWindowEx(), the child window is too small...

Here is the code I use within the MainWndProc to create a child window:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg,
                             WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC          hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT  ps;

    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                //OnCreate(hWnd, NULL);
                CLIENTCREATESTRUCT ccs;

                ccs.hWindowMenu  = GetSubMenu(GetMenu(hWnd), 2);
                ccs.idFirstChild = StartChildrenNo;

                hWndChildFrame = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                    L"MDICLIENT",
                    NULL,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VSCROLL
                    | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VISIBLE,
                    0,
                    0,
                    1024,
                    768,
                    hWnd,
                    (HMENU)IDM_FILE_NEW,
                    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                    (LPVOID)&ccs);

                if(hWndChildFrame == NULL)
                    MessageBox(hWnd, L"Could not create MDI client.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

                CreateNewMDIChild(hWndChildFrame);              
                                return 0;
            }
```

...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To determine size how the MDI child window can be large, use `GetClientRect()` of the MDI client window.
2. To compute needed window size for the MDI child window use `AdjustWindowRect()` or `AdjustWindowRectEx()`. Those can convert between window and client size.